# Want to create buttons like the image shown below

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to create an html page exactly like the demo image:

[image]

I have created all three buttons using anchor tag with data-role=button with corresponding color and text. But now what i want is to align those circles in the way the image is shown and bring them in center of the html page. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a Fiddle with your code **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**. Though you will probably need to use `position:absolute;` to get them to overlap.

Comment: you need to demonstrate that you have a basic understanding of what your trying to achieve to get help. Adding an image doesn't do this. Ps you can just embed images into the question, you don't need to use github

Comment: @Liam Don't you need a certain amount of rep to embed images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ey6Yb/1/

**HTML :**

```
<div id="button-container">
    <a data-role="button" id="btn_gotohomepage" class="button_eclipse">My account</a> 
    <a data-role="button" id="btn_gotologinpage" class="button_eclipse">Services</a>
    <a data-role="button" id="btn_gotolistpage" class="button_eclipse">Offers</a>                    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#button-container {
    width: 145px;
    height: 255px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.button_eclipse {
    width: 100px !important;
    height: 100px !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;
}

.button_eclipse .ui-btn-inner {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    height: 80% !important;
}

.button_eclipse .ui-btn-inner  .ui-btn-text { 
    display: block !important;
    margin: 28px 0 0 -17px;
    width: 95px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    /* TEXT CHANGES */
    font: 14px Calibri,Arial !important;  
    text-shadow:1px 1px #AD4816 !important;
}

#btn_gotohomepage {
    background: rgb(247,107,33) !important;    
}

#btn_gotologinpage {
    background: rgb(255,165,33) !important;  
    margin: -30px 0 0 40px;
}

#btn_gotolistpage {
    background: rgb(157,16,33) !important;  
    margin: -30px 0 0 0;    
}
```

**EDIT :**

Here's a solution centered horizontally and vertically : http://jsfiddle.net/Ey6Yb/3/

Comment: Do you also need it vertically centered?

Comment: Yes, if its possible then please tell.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ey6Yb/3/

Answer (score 2):

Change in your css file with below script:

```
.ui-content {
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 150px;
}

.btn_eclipse_services {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFA521 !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    height: 100px !important;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 100px !important;
}

.btn_eclipse_offers {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9C1021 !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    height: 100px !important;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

and for more you can check this link **[How to Center Anything With CSS](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/)**